# Excel vba catch grouping outline level (+, -) button pressed

Tags: vba, excel

When certain Rows or Columns are grouped then user will be able to see a + (Plus) sign to expand all the rows or columns grouped together. Once all the rows or columns are expanded then user will be able to see a – (Minus) sign to collapse them. Now what is nested grouping? As Nested means Nested grouping is Grouping within a Group.

now i use mouse pointer catch, but it do not catch nested groups

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long

Private Type POINTAPI
x As Long
y As Long
End Type

Public z As POINTAPI

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim lRow As Long

        Application.EnableEvents = False
        'get mouse pinter
        GetCursorPos z
        'check if mouse pressed
        If ActiveWindow.RangeFromPoint(z.x, z.y) Is Nothing Then
            'found row near pointer
            On Error Resume Next
            lRow = ActiveWindow.RangeFromPoint(z.x + 300, z.y).Row
            ' check if this row hidden
            If Rows(lRow + 1).Hidden = False Then
                MsgBox ("Opened " & Rows(lRow + 1).OutlineLevel)
            Else
                MsgBox ("Hidened " & Rows(lRow + 1).OutlineLevel)
            End If
        End If

        Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

How to catch one of pressed (Row levels or Column levels) (+,- or 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8(nested group)) button

[image]

As i can only

```
Sub Expand_All()
    ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=8, ColumnLevels:=8
End Sub
```

and

```
Sub Collapse_All()
    ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1, ColumnLevels:=1
End Sub
```

and

check for hidden rows, but i need check state of button pressed as to control it from ribbon.
something like

```
Sub Outline_Click() '(+ or - or one of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
    msgbox "pressed " & Application.Caller
end Sub
```

Comment: keep in mind that many users can't see the images as they use SO at work and normally those sharing sites are blocked then.

Comment: So that your suggestion for images?

Comment: a really good explanation of the situation.

Comment: I don't think I'd say "many users" have images blocked.  If so, they're going to have plenty of problems on this site.  IMO, In this case an image is much preferred to a lengthy explanation.

Comment: I recently gave up on something similar I was trying to do so I'm curious if someone has an idea of a tidy way to do this.  I figure [the `range.ShowDetail` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-showdetail-property-excel) will be involved, perhaps similarly to how you're using `.Hidden`.